# Auspicious Time for Tefillah After Mitzva?

Tags: tefilla

Is there a source that it is an especially auspicious time to daven after completing a mitzva? There are many Yehi Ratzons after fulfilling various mitzvos (shabbos candles, arba minim, etc.), but I haven't found a source for general mitzvos.

Answer (score 3):

While this text is usually read as talking about how to approach prayer, it seems to answer your question as well.  Gemara in Berakhot 31a says:

> תָּנוּ רַבָּנַן: אֵין עוֹמְדִין לְהִתְפַּלֵּל לֹא מִתּוֹךְ עַצְבוּת,
>   וְלֹא מִתּוֹךְ עַצְלוּת, וְלֹא מִתּוֹךְ שְׂחוֹק, וְלֹא מִתּוֹךְ
>   שִׂיחָה, וְלֹא מִתּוֹךְ קַלּוּת רֹאשׁ, וְלֹא מִתּוֹךְ דְּבָרִים
>   בְּטֵלִים, אֶלָּא מִתּוֹךְ שִׂמְחָה שֶׁל מִצְוָה.
>
> On the topic of proper preparation for prayer, the Sages taught: One
>   may neither stand to pray from an atmosphere of sorrow nor from an
>   atmosphere of laziness, nor from an atmosphere of laughter, nor from
>   an atmosphere of conversation, nor from an atmosphere of frivolity,
>   nor from an atmosphere of purposeless matters. Rather, one should
>   approach prayer from an atmosphere imbued with the joy of a mitzva.

So having done a mitzvah, one presumably has the joy of having done a mitzvah and now is a good time to pray.